# Is there a way to reference an active cell in a formula in VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

We have a program that requires a very specific format to upload certain fields, and the fields vary in character length. However, if they are short, they need blank spaces. The convention is 10 digits-10 digits-10 digits-10 digits including spaces, e.g.

`|ABC123    -ABCDEF    -ABCDEFGH  -ABC      |`

We receive a lot of reports with formatting that needs to be corrected. I am trying to create a macro that would apply this formatting to whatever cell is currently highlighted. Is there a way to do that? Or, to apply it to a range of cells if that isn't possible (i.e. A2:A100)? I assume I would need to loop.

My first step is to remove all the spaces in a cell (because the spacing is often incorrect):
Dim w As Range

```
For Each w In Selection.Cells
    w = Replace(w, " ", "")
```

Next step is to apply the formula to the cell (which I'm not sure how to do). In this example, I'd like to replace the reference "A2" with something like Active.cell (I know that doesn't work):

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",(LEFT(A2,5)&"     "&"-")&(IF((LEN(MID(A2,SEARCH("-",A2)+1,SEARCH("-",A2,SEARCH("-",A2)+1)-SEARCH("-",A2)-1)))<10,(MID(A2,SEARCH("-",A2)+1,SEARCH("-",A2,SEARCH("-",A2)+1)-SEARCH("-",A2)-1)&REPT(" ",10-LEN(MID(A2,SEARCH("-",A2)+1,SEARCH("-",A2,SEARCH("-",A2)+1)-SEARCH("-",A2)-1)))&"-"),MID(A2,SEARCH("-",A2)+1,SEARCH("-",A2,SEARCH("-",A2)+1)-SEARCH("-",A2)-1)&"-"))&( IF((LEN(MID(A2,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",CHAR(1),2))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",CHAR(1),3))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",CHAR(1),2))-1)))<10,(MID(A2,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",CHAR(1),2))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",CHAR(1),3))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",CHAR(1),2))-1)&REPT(" ",10-LEN(MID(A2,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",CHAR(1),2))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",CHAR(1),3))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",CHAR(1),2))-1)))&"-"),MID(A2,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",CHAR(1),2))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",CHAR(1),3))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",CHAR(1),2))-1)&"-")) &(IF((LEN(MID(A2,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",CHAR(1),3))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",CHAR(1),3))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",CHAR(1),2))-1)))<10,(MID(A2,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",CHAR(1),3))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",CHAR(1),3))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",CHAR(1),2))-1)&REPT(" ",10-LEN(MID(A2,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",CHAR(1),3))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",CHAR(1),3))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",CHAR(1),2))-1)))&"-"),MID(A2,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",CHAR(1),3))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",CHAR(1),3))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",CHAR(1),2))-1)&"-")))
```

Thank you.

```
I tried using active.cell. This did not work:
=(LEFT(ACTIVE.CELL,5)&"     "&"-")&(IF((LEN(MID(ACTIVE.CELL,SEARCH("-",ACTIVE.CELL)+1,SEARCH("-",ACTIVE.CELL,SEARCH("-",ACTIVE.CELL)+1)-SEARCH("-",ACTIVE.CELL)-1)))<10,(MID(ACTIVE.CELL,SEARCH("-",ACTIVE.CELL)+1,SEARCH("-",ACTIVE.CELL,SEARCH("-",ACTIVE.CELL)+1)-SEARCH("-",ACTIVE.CELL)-1)&REPT(" ",10-LEN(MID(ACTIVE.CELL,SEARCH("-",ACTIVE.CELL)+1,SEARCH("-",ACTIVE.CELL,SEARCH("-",ACTIVE.CELL)+1)-SEARCH("-",ACTIVE.CELL)-1)))&"-"),MID(ACTIVE.CELL,SEARCH("-",ACTIVE.CELL)+1,SEARCH("-",ACTIVE.CELL,SEARCH("-",ACTIVE.CELL)+1)-SEARCH("-",ACTIVE.CELL)-1)&"-"))&( IF((LEN(MID(ACTIVE.CELL,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(ACTIVE.CELL,"-",CHAR(1),2))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(ACTIVE.CELL,"-",CHAR(1),3))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(ACTIVE.CELL,"-",CHAR(1),2))-1)))<10,(MID(ACTIVE.CELL,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(ACTIVE.CELL,"-",CHAR(1),2))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(ACTIVE.CELL,"-",CHAR(1),3))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(ACTIVE.CELL,"-",CHAR(1),2))-1)&REPT(" ",10-LEN(MID(ACTIVE.CELL,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(ACTIVE.CELL,"-",CHAR(1),2))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(ACTIVE.CELL,"-",CHAR(1),3))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(ACTIVE.CELL,"-",CHAR(1),2))-1)))&"-"),MID(ACTIVE.CELL,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(ACTIVE.CELL,"-",CHAR(1),2))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(ACTIVE.CELL,"-",CHAR(1),3))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(ACTIVE.CELL,"-",CHAR(1),2))-1)&"-")) &(IF((LEN(MID(ACTIVE.CELL,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(ACTIVE.CELL,"-",CHAR(1),3))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(ACTIVE.CELL,"-",CHAR(1),3))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(ACTIVE.CELL,"-",CHAR(1),2))-1)))<10,(MID(ACTIVE.CELL,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(ACTIVE.CELL,"-",CHAR(1),3))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(ACTIVE.CELL,"-",CHAR(1),3))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(ACTIVE.CELL,"-",CHAR(1),2))-1)&REPT(" ",10-LEN(MID(ACTIVE.CELL,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(ACTIVE.CELL,"-",CHAR(1),3))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(ACTIVE.CELL,"-",CHAR(1),3))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(ACTIVE.CELL,"-",CHAR(1),2))-1)))&"-"),MID(ACTIVE.CELL,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(ACTIVE.CELL,"-",CHAR(1),3))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(ACTIVE.CELL,"-",CHAR(1),3))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(ACTIVE.CELL,"-",CHAR(1),2))-1)&"-"))
```

Comment: "10 digits-10 digits-10 digits-10 digits" - your example doesn't seem to follow that pattern?   Some examples of "before" and "after" would be useful here.  FYI a "digit" is specifically 0-9, and a "character" can be a number or a letter. It seems like you mean "10 characters" not "10 digits" ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should add input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

try below replace the formula with your own formula and
replace `A2` with `" & cell.Address & "`

```
Sub ReplaceSpacesAndApplyFormula()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Selection
        
        cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, " ", "")
        
        ' Put the formula to the cell right of the selected cell
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=IF(" & cell.Address & ">1,""Yes"",""No"")"
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you want.

```vb
Function CheckId(v)
    Dim arr, el, i As Long
    arr = Split(v, "-")   'split on dash
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        'trim and pad with spaces up to length 10
        arr(i) = Left(Trim(arr(i)) & String(10, " "), 10)
    Next i
    CheckId = Join(arr, "-") 're-join values
End Function
```

Put the code in a regular module and call it from a worksheet cell like

`=CheckId(a1)`

Answer (score 0):

This code worked perfectly, thank you!

```vb
Sub ReplaceSpacesAndApplyFormula()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Selection
        
        cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, " ", "")
        
        ' Put the formula to the cell right of the selected cell
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=IF((LEN(MID(" & cell.Address & ",FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(" & cell.Address & ",""-"",CHAR(1),3))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(" & cell.Address & ",""-"",CHAR(1),3))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(" & cell.Address & ",""-"",CHAR(1),2)))))<10,(MID(" & cell.Address & ",FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(" & cell.Address & ",""-"",CHAR(1),3))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(" & cell.Address & ",""-"",CHAR(1),3))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(" & cell.Address & ",""-"",CHAR(1),2)))&REPT("" "",10-LEN(MID(" & cell.Address & ",FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(" & cell.Address & ",""-"",CHAR(1),3))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(" & cell.Address & ",""-"",CHAR(1),3))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(" & cell.Address & ",""-"",CHAR(1),2)))))),MID(" & cell.Address & ",FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(" & cell.Address & ",""-"",CHAR(1),3))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(" & cell.Address & ",""-"",CHAR(1),3))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(" & cell.Address & ",""-"",CHAR(1),2))))" & _
""
    Next cell
End Sub
```